# Trying to add "disabled='disabled'" to a select option on an adminhtml form - 1.9.0.1 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

I have an array of all regions and a collection of all currently "used" regions which are assigned to my entity.  I would like the select box to show all regions, but the ones that are currently "used" will be disabled.  I'm hoping there's a way to do this, and I don't have to resort to JS.

Part of the form in which I need disabled options:

```
'remainingRegions' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Remaining Regions'),
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'values' => Mage::helper('dos')->GetRemainingRegions((int)$origin->getEntityId()),
        )
```

Here is GetRemainingRegions():

```
    public function GetRemainingRegions()
{
    $regionArray = array();
    $allAssignedRegions = Mage::getResourceModel('dos/states_collection')->load()->getItems();
    $allRegions = $this->GetRegions(FALSE);

    if(count($allAssignedRegions))
    {
        foreach($allRegions as $key => $region)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($region['value'],$allAssignedRegions))
            {
                unset($allRegions[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    $regionArray = $allRegions;

    return $regionArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible to disable without using javascript or rewriting some core files.

Take a look code below, all valid attributes are predefine

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget

```
protected function _setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset, $exclude=array())
{
    $this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
     .....
            $element = $fieldset->addField($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $fieldType,
                array(
                    'name'      => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'label'     => $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
                    'class'     => $attribute->getFrontend()->getClass(),
                    'required'  => $attribute->getIsRequired(),
                    'note'      => $attribute->getNote(),
                )
            )
```

You could easily accomplish this using javascript see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356608/how-to-change-comments-data-with-onchange-function-in-addfield-in-magento

Comment: Yes, this is what I discovered today as well.  For now, I had given up, and decided to just not display the ones I would like disabled.  But you answer in the link you provides seems to be a quick fix that is the next best thing I can hope for!  Thanks!